# MySQL Query to collect unique IDs that are X seconds more than selected ID

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table with user IDS and a timestamp. I am looking to collect the distinct userids for the given day (2021-09-03 in this case). However if the date and time of the userid is greater than X seconds then I want to print this userid as well (as I know this is not a duplicate).

In other words a user enters the system and it logs him in (this is a true login), however it may log him in several times in the database, several rows of repeat data where the seconds or milliseconds differ (as a result of a number of legacy systems). He may log in again 10 seconds later (or any time frame later) - this is another true login (but might also contain several rows of login again). Therefore I want to show the userid and date and time for only the true logins.

```
rowid   userid  dateandtime
10      0       2021-09-03 18:48:44.517771
11      0       2021-09-03 18:48:44.873727
12      0       2021-09-03 18:48:44.936010
13      0       2021-09-03 18:48:45.158109
14      0       2021-09-03 18:48:46.385015
15      10      2021-09-03 18:49:00.433325
16      0       2021-09-03 20:03:35.584817
17      0       2021-09-03 20:03:35.633030
18      0       2021-09-03 20:03:36.679559
19      0       2021-09-03 20:03:37.726138
20      4357    2021-09-03 22:41:43.549345
21      4357    2021-09-03 22:41:44.127240
22      4357    2021-09-03 22:41:44.168634
23      4357    2021-09-03 22:41:44.454468
```

So you can see userid 0 logged in at 2021-09-03 18:48:44.517771. The other legacy systems continued to log him in for several seconds and milliseconds (these are the false logins).
Then user 10 logged in at 2021-09-03 18:49:00.433325 and user 0 legitimately logged in again at 2021-09-03 20:03:35.584817 (and false logins) followed by user 4357 at 2021-09-03 22:41:43.549345 (and then false logins again for this user).

I need to create a MySQL query to clean out the noise and just result with the true logins:

```
rowid   userid  dateandtime
10      0       2021-09-03 18:48:44.517771
15      10      2021-09-03 18:49:00.433325
16      0       2021-09-03 20:03:35.584817
20      4357    2021-09-03 22:41:43.549345
```

So distinct logins where the date and time is greater than X seconds for the given user.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the `LAG()` window function should be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the time in seconds with the previous login by the same user using the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and `LAG` functions.

```
SET @X = 1; -- X seconds

WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT *,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
      second, 
      LAG(dateandtime) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY dateandtime), 
      dateandtime
    ) AS seconds
  FROM t
) 
SELECT rowid, userid, dateandtime
FROM t1
WHERE seconds IS NULL OR seconds > @X
ORDER BY dateandtime
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e664abe09ccb9db5e9444c355e60f7e2)

Comment: Does this take into account if a second or third user logged in at the same time as well? So the true next user login was mixed up in the false previous user login? That is while the false user logins were being entered into rows a true (another) user logged in and then had his false logins also entered mixed with previous user.

Comment: The logon accounting of different users is not mixed. The time in seconds from the previous login is counted for each user separately. This is achieved using the `PARTITION BY userid` clause. Test it in the fiddle.

Comment: Excellent query!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `lag()` to see the previous user and then filter:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(userid) over (order by dateandtime) as prev_userid
      from t
     ) t
where prev_userid is null or prev_userid <> userid;
```

Comment: This would only work if there are no sequential "true" logins from a given user without an intervening "true" login from another user. So if user X logs in, and an hour later they log in again (with no intervening activity from any other user), this would only show their first login, not their second. So either OP doesn't realize this is a loophole, or hasn't told us that this loophole isn't possible for other reasons.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the inner query have to `ORDER BY dateandtime`?